# How to center text in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to center text in kivy. I tried using `halign="center"` like so:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import CoreLabel
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle, Color
from kivy.core.window import Window

class MyWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.canvas.clear()

        with self.canvas:
            Color(0, 0, 0, 1)

            label = CoreLabel(text="Text", font_size=50, halign="center")
            label.refresh()
            text = label.texture
            Rectangle(size=text.size, pos=(865, 30), texture=text)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

But that doesn't center the text around the given position (it is still left aligned). If I change the length of the text (and therefore its size), its position doesn't change, even though I want it to.

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) addressing your main problem.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is that the text is already center aligned, and the rectangle you're putting it in is sized to the text, so changing halign does nothing.  You need to change the field size to the width you want it to fill.  see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31638788/python-kivy-align-text-to-the-left-side-of-a-label/31638889#31638889

Comment: @nigh_anxiety While setting the rectangle size to the size I want it to fill does make the centering work correctly, it also stretches the text to fill the entire width.

Answer (score -2):

Try adding

```
label = CoreLabel(halign='center',valign='center')
```